# Ожидание ввода данных после подключения к сокету

Tags: php, сокет

Пишу клиент-серверное приложение. Не могу понять, как сделать так, что бы после удачного подключения к сокету, скрипт ждал ввода данных.

```
try {
    //get answer
    while ($answer = socket_read($this->sock, 1024)) {
        if (false === $answer) {
            throw new Exception('socket_read() failed: ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n");
        } else {
            //add answer in buffer
            $this->inBuffer($answer, 0);
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    //TODO пишем в логи БД ошибку
}
```

В данном случае скрипт считывает пустую строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем добавил проверку на пустую строку:

```
while ($answer = socket_read($this->masterSocket, 1024)) {
    if (false === $answer) {
        throw new Exception('socket_read() failed: ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n");
    } elseif (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
        //прочитана пустая строка, продолжаем читать
        continue;
    } else {
        //add answer in buffer
        $this->inBuffer($answer, 0);
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый @ХэшКод  
Нельзя ли как-то сделать, что бы вопросы, на которые сам себе отвечаешь, можно было закрыть без ущерба для статистики принятых ответов?